# Find relationship in two time series datasets

Tags: time-series, correlation, causality

I have two datasets:

1. Ingested ingredients at a point in time

e.g.

| 24/04/2016 11:56:33 | Tomatoe    |
| 24/04/2016 11:56:33 | White rice |
| 24/04/2016 14:34:01 | Mars Bar   |

2. Symptoms

| 24/04/2016 12:45:05 | Flatulence    |
| 24/04/2016 14:34:01 | Stomach Pain   |

Could anyone point me in the direction of how I could find relationships between these two datasets. I can see 2 things which may be important

1. The proximity of the cause to the event (if a symptom arose a minute after the ingredient was ingested it seems unlikely to be the cause.
2. That a symptom isn't an event at a singular point in time and may slowly get worse, then slowly get better.

Any suggestion or links to resources would be appreciated. BTW I'm not a mathematician.

Thanks